# alternative for sleep function

Tags: iphone, sleep

I have implemented following in my application.

```
for(i=0;!stopThroughButtons && i<totalMovements;i++){
        [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(moveNeedle) toTarget:self withObject:nil];
        sleep(0.3);
    }
```

Here the `sleep` is a function with argument of `unsigned int` type.

Sleep method uses seconds to sleep.

I want to give the timing in milliseconds to sleep.

Which best alternate is available?

Comment: sleep() is the wrong answer. See below.

Comment: ok. but now I had removed sleep from my logic & I used timer instead the sleep & thread. Ok @bbum. Your comment gave me attention to that point.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Two options:
`int usleep(useconds_t useconds)`
 will use microseconds
`int nanosleep(const struct timespec *rqtp, struct timespec *rmtp)` will use nanoseconds

Comment: finally I implemented this. & it works.


for(i=0;!stopThroughButtons && i<totalMovements;i++){
   if(i>=9)
    break;
   [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(moveNeedle) toTarget:self withObject:nil];
   usleep(200000);
  }

Comment: See cdespinosa's answer below.  Using sleep() is almost always the wrong answer.

Comment: ok. but now I had removed sleep from my logic & I used timer instead the sleep & thread. Ok @bbum. Your comment gave me attention to that point.

Comment: Note that depending on the platform, usleep with larger number than 1,000,000 might not work: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12175106/is-it-safe-to-use-usleep-in-ubuntu-with-value-greater-than-1000000

Answer (score 37):

There's also NSThread's +sleepForTimeInterval:, which takes time in fractional seconds.  For example:

```
[NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:0.05];
```

should sleep for 50 milliseconds.

Answer (score 16):

As has been mentioned in the other thread you started, you probably don't want to sleep on the main thread, as that blocks event delivery and freezes the UI.  Instead of looping and sleeping, you probably want to fire a timer and perform your action when the timer fires.

Comment: ok. but now I had removed sleep from my logic & I used timer instead the sleep & thread. Ok @bbum. Your comment gave me attention to that point.

Comment: In UI Testing, sleep methods, can be useful because the test app is running on a different process than the tested app.

Answer (score 3):

You probably want `nanosleep()` instead, which takes nanoseconds. Bear in mind these sleep times are not accurate though, so what you really have is the ability to specify it more accurately than a few hundredths of seconds.

Comment: nanosleep(<#const struct timespec * #>, <#struct timespec * #>)
Sir, Would you please tell me, what to pass as arguments?