# Is it safe to use usleep in Ubuntu with value greater than 1000000

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu

I saw in [usleep man](http://linux.die.net/man/3/usleep) that :

```
EINVAL
usec is not smaller than 1000000. (On systems where that is considered an error.)
```

So i wonder if its ok to use usleep in **Ubuntu** with value greater than 1000000 and if not (or in case that i want to support other platforms ) what is the alternative when i need sleep for 2.2 sec (for example) .

Thank you.

Comment: Call `usleep()` with the large value on your system and check `errno`?

Comment: @Christian.K That would mean the application takes at least a second to boot.

Comment: For what it's worth, POSIX doesn't require that [usleep](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/usleep.html) nor [nanosleep](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/nanosleep.html) work for more than one second.

Comment: How about this ugly solution: `sleep(2); usleep(200000);`

Comment: @Potatoswatter  can you explain?

Comment: @Potatoswatter I wasn't assuming the OP wants to do that every time he launches his app, but rather doing it once to answer his main question "is it supported on Ubuntu". Of course, that is moot, because you still risk portability / correctness. But that was not the point of my comment :-)

Comment: @user1495181 The two pages I linked, which are from the international standard that defines the APIs, mention that these functions might not allow it. But see my answer; I don't think these POSIX limitations are really relevant to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One alternative is to trust the documentation and implement it using a loop just to be safe:

```
#define USLEEP_MAX (1000000 - 1)

void long_sleep(unsigned long micros)
{
  while(micros > 0)
  {
    const unsigned long chunk = micros > USLEEP_MAX ? USLEEP_MAX : micros;
    usleep(chunk);
    micros -= chunk;
  }
}
```

You should also inspect the return value of `usleep()`, I omitted that for brevity.

In production, you can have fun with [Autoconf](http://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/) and friends to detect the proper `USLEEP_MAX` at compile-time, and even switch to a plain wrapper if the local system doesn't have a limit for the argument. Hours of fun can be had.

Comment: That drifts, by up to timeslice a timeslice per second. It might be better to `sleep` for one big interval then `usleep` for the rest, but precision isn't really guaranteed for any particular call.

Comment: I can confirm that calling usleep and passing 1e6 results in no delay, under mingw in windows.

Answer (score 1):

You'd have to look at the Linux kernel source to be 100% sure, but considering that Ubuntu is only distributed for x86 and x86-64, and someone would soon find that sort of behavior unacceptable regardless of whether it's allowed by the underlying [POSIX spec](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/usleep.html), chances are essentially nil that it will ever break.

Linux is ported to a huge variety of systems ports can adopt other ugly preexisting kernel code, so I think the manpage author was just covering his ass when he adapted the POSIX (or whatever) spec which reflects the very loose requirements designed to accommodate odd microcontrollers with slapdash kernels.